# Cleaning up empty file references from collaborated Xcode projects

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, git

What are these empty shells in my Xcode filesystem and what's the procedure to remove them safely? Also did a search for duplicate refs in the Xcode File Navigator but didn't find any.

**Sidenote:** Project is collaborated via git and I suspect that has something to do with their presence. Occasionally after merging feature branches we get conflicts in myproject.pbxproj file and must manually resolve conflicts by deleting duplicate file refs so maybe some slipped through. For anyone who's been in a similar mess: what's the standard way to clean it up?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I was facing the same issue while merging:

It is because of your `project.pbxproj` file not updated successfully. For each file we add, its reference is added in  project.pbxproj file.here, these files is already having entry for your project.pbxproj file(like E00021389E899 if you look closure to your file) and another user also adds the same file then, 2 entries will be there in your  project.pbxproj file for the same .h/.m thats why it is showing this error.

For cleanup purpose, you can simply right click and delete that file. There won't be any issue. and also don't forget to update your code regularly. If you ever have conflicts in your project.pbxproj, than you need to resolve it properly or try to get a fresh copy.